# Saving "Find result window" in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I used notepad++ 6.7.5 to do several searches on a number of opened documents and this showed the " Find result window/pane " with all my Finds. The Find result window helps me to find texts in their respective documents when I simply double click them. 
  Is there a way to save the "Find result window" with all the words I have found in it? Or, is there a way to save session with the Find result window?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there isn't a specific way of doing this.

This workaround may help:

The results `Find result` page are highlightable so it is possible to select all results by clicking in the page and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.  These selected results can then be pasted in a file and they keep their original formatting.

Comment: Yeah that is possible. But with that, I cannot find words in their respective documents by simply double clicking on it. The finds are many and I need a quick way of finding them in their documents as I work on each of them. Thanks anyway, your response was so quick.

Comment: So like you said, there isn't a specific way of doing this, but how about suggesting a similar program that can do it. Are the any other alternative programs?

Answer (score 2):

The functionality of what you are wanting can be achieved (in a somewhat cumbersome way) by recording each search as a Notepad++ macro. You can record each of your searches as a separately named Macro, which on 'Stop Recording' will then be accessible via the Macro menu pull-down. Or you could record a number of different searches, one after the other, and save the resulting sequence of multiple searches as a single macro (which will then similarly be accessible from the Macro pull-down menu.)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. They want to save the result panel.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand what you want done correctly, but how about this:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- Mark
- Enter search term
- Check the "bookmark line" option
- Search > Bookmark > Copy bookmarked lines
- Paste in new text file.

Comment: Some helpful advice.  You should avoid submitting answers to a question when what the author of the question wants isn't clear.  It makes it nearly impossible to post an answer that is helpful to all with the same problem.  Instead you should submit comments to get clarification you need to actual answer the question they asked. If that is not possible, because of your reputation, you should stick to questions you can answer without submitting comments.

Comment: Alright, I guess I should make some clarifications then. What am saying is, notepad++ provides you with a " search result window/pane " when you conduct multiple searches. Now the question is, how do I save this window?

Comment: The question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Truth is.. you can't. And this is a bummer, especially on shared machines where you need to perform a very large search and after 2 hours when the searched would've been over you notice somebody closed notepad++..
In my case, I had a very very large environment (about 1.1 million files) and had to search for a specific Python construct which relied on a non-backwards compatible behaviour - in order to assess the impact of an update. This is a search which takes some time even on fast machines.